# Windows XP style compact path in Windows 7 file browser window

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, file-management, path

I do lots of navigating between folders trying to keep projects synced and I've tried using things like winmerge but they're too clunky and slow. I switched back to old fashioned windows explorer but the navigation pane on the left takes up way too much space and is completely useless since it doesn't even show your path when you're in a folder with many files/subfolders. The best way to display files for me is to have 47 file browser windows open at the same time in an organized way and transfer between them.

The problem with that is I can't see what drive I'm on or the first half of the path because Microsoft saw fit to put giant arrows in the Windows 7 path bar instead of the nice little backslash that's actually in the path. **How do I get the backslashes back instead of arrows**?

Comment: I suppose an alternative solution would be a file management program like a super uber filezilla 10000 with tons of paths and programmable smart file operations like sync from one location to another unidirectionally or notify if this file updates or merge all changes between these two folders if it's thursday but never modify anything in these on friday or the weekend... Hmmm... anyone want to help out with this project? (I'm serious, btw. I'll post back here when I start this as open source project.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Hope I'm not missing something you've said, but what I always do is click on the icon to the left of the unhelpful location text with the arrows - Doing that changes it to the proper, complete path.

HTH.

edit:

The keyboard shortcut to the address bar is <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>.  You can also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>.

Comment: That *is* a great momentary fix if you want to use a mouse but I'd have to alt tab, grab the mouse, click, alt tab grab the mouse, click, ad insaniam... (why yes, I think I *DID* just coin a new twist on ad infinitum)

Comment: Keyboard shortcuts added.

Comment: F4 works too, and it even show the recent path list

Comment: I was really looking for a way to make it stay by default but this is a sufficient bandaid.